# Building a recursive representation of trie from compact trie in python

Tags: python, trie

I am now writing a code that builds a compact trie from a key set which is URL list.
Then I wanna store this data structure in a recursive trie representation like below:

```
T = |L| A B
|L| is the number of leaves of a left subtrie
A is a left subtrie
B is a right subtrie
```

Here is my part of python code.

```
def leftLeaves(self, node):
          if node.isLeaf():
              return 1
          else:
              return self.leftLeaves(node.left) + self.leftLeaves(node.right)

def toBitStream(self, node):
      if node.isLeaf():
          return [node.path.length(), node.path, -1]
      else:
          L = node.left
          R = node.right
          leftLeaves = self.leftLeaves(L)
         return [node.path.length(), node.path, leftLeaves] + self.toBitStream(L) + self.toBitStream(R)
```

When I run this script, I encounter

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

But I input small size of a keyset, it doesn't matter.

I know the runtime error is due to python limits a depth of recursive call to avoid stack overflow.

Is there any other solutions to solve this except using sys.setrecursionlimit call (For example, converting to iterative procedure)? It comes out Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: Are you certain that you aren't in an infinite loop? If you try this with a very small input, do you still get this?

Comment: Also, the stack trace usually reveals quite clearly what the path was, and whether it's an infinite recursion.

Comment: No, I don't have any error with a very small input until 1000. But it comes out over 1000.